# How to make terminal title to stick on Macs

Tags: ssh, unix, macbook-pro, terminal.app, title

I'm not sure if this is a problem with my mac, of which I'm a noob with, or if it's a setting of the server I'm sshing into.

What I'm doing is this:

1. Open a new window in terminal
2. SSH into a CentOS server.  My login shell is bash.
3. Click on Shell->Edit Title
4. Change the title and the tab title to abc123.  It gets reflected in the terminal title bar as abc123-abc123-ssh-100x24
5. In the terminal, run 'sudo su' to change user to root.  Note the title has now changed to root@blah:/home/myuser-ssh-100x24.  If I log out of root, the title name is still this new name.

How do you make the title name stick as abc123 and not change when I su to other users?
Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The title is set from the server you're connecting to. Chances are, `/etc/bashrc` or a similar file defines `PROMPT_COMMAND` to set the title. On CentOS 6, it looks like this:

```
  if [ -z "$PROMPT_COMMAND" ]; then
    case $TERM in
    xterm*)
        if [ -e /etc/sysconfig/bash-prompt-xterm ]; then
            PROMPT_COMMAND=/etc/sysconfig/bash-prompt-xterm
        else
            PROMPT_COMMAND='printf "\033]0;%s@%s:%s\007" "${USER}" "${HOSTNAME%%.*}" "${PWD/#$HOME/~}"'
        fi
        ;;
[... more of the same ...]
      esac
  fi
```

To prevent this, make sure to set `PROMPT_COMMAND=` in `root`'s and your own bash configuration files on the server you SSH into (e.g. `~/.bashrc`).

Alternatively, add `PROMPT_COMMAND` to `/etc/sudoers` (`env_keep`) and `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` (`AcceptEnv`) to inherit it from the local system, and set it to a value that does not affect the title bar.

In this specific case, you could also set your Terminal declare a different Terminal, as this is only set for `xterm*` on CentOS (*Terminal » Preferences… » Settings » (Select Profile) » Advanced » Declare Terminal as*).

---

Terminal.app does not seem to allow to lock the title – you're probably expected to change the configuration that sets it as described above. You could always check out a different terminal, such as iTerm. It supports keeping the *profile name* in the title even the title changes.

---

And here's a dirty hack to keep your terminal title without changing the configuration of all servers you SSH into:

In the same shell you SSH into your Linux box, before you do that, run the following command:

```
while true ; do printf "\033]0;%s\007" "My Terminal Title" ; sleep 1 ; done &
```

This will execute a loop in the background that changes the terminal title to *My Terminal Title* once a second, overriding any changes performed in your SSH session.

Once you're done, use job control in your shell to stop it (`jobs` and `kill %1` if it's the first job), or `fg` to bring it to foreground, and cancel with `Ctrl-C`.